# bash send string argument as multiple arguments

Tags: string, bash, variable-expansion

So I have a bash script that is generating a string of commands that I want to be run. The output looks something like

`$ program "command1 command2 ... commandN"`

But the program is interpreting (as it should) "command1 command2 ... commandN" as one argument.

Is there away to turn pass the string into the argument as split arguments so the program would interpret each command as an individual argument?

`$ program command1 command2 ... commandN`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You might need to escape the spaces using a Edit: forwardslash

Comment: Can you post your bash script code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've done this, implementing your scenario :
The idea is to use "a b c" as argument for `cat`

```
$ echo a > a
$ echo b > b
$ echo c > c
$ args="a b c"
```

Trying "a b c" as "one argument"

```
$ cat $args
cat: a b c: No such file or directory
```

Workaround to separate arguments :

```
$ cat $(echo $args)
a
b
c
```

Hope it helps you

(So you should run `program $(echo "command1 command2 ... commandN")`

Comment: This is not safe for arguments that can themselves contain spaces and/or which contain shell metacharacters. The correct way to do this is to use an array or arguments and not a string see [Bash FAQ 0050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for more details.

Comment: This works with shell, which makes me happy. Thank you

Comment: Hmmm, in my environment it is not the case. `cat $args` output `a`, `b`, `c`. It splits $args, but not "$args".

Comment: You maybe used an custom `IFS`, but `$(echo $args)` should not work either in such case.

Answer (score 2):

You can rely on [Bash's Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html).

```bash
root@036717c8f088:/# x="a b c";cat $x
cat: a: No such file or directory
cat: b: No such file or directory
cat: c: No such file or directory
```

The only thing you need to do is NOT adding double quotes.

```bash
root@036717c8f088:/# x="a b c";cat "$x"
cat: 'a b c': No such file or directory
```

If you don't want to define a variable, you can use `expr`:

```bash
root@036717c8f088:/# cat $(expr "a b c")
cat: a: No such file or directory
cat: b: No such file or directory
cat: c: No such file or directory
```

Thus, the answer can be:

```bash
program $(expr "command1 command2 ... commandN")
```

If the word splitting doesn't work, it might be caused by `IFS`, you can `unset IFS`.

Answer (score 0):

I love the **xargs** command which takes your quoted string as input and runs the program. For feeding xargs you use the pipe "|"

A dummy "program.sh":

```
$ cat program.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is my 1st argument: $1"
echo "This is my 2nd argument: $2"
echo "This is my 3rd argument: $3"

$ ARGS='command1 command2 command3'
$ echo "$ARGS" | xargs ./program.sh
This is my 1st argument: command1
This is my 2nd argument: command2
This is my 3rd argument: command3
```

Note that $ARGS has been quoted explicitely.
The main advantage of this method is that xargs has plenty of options.